# Dynamic load data ASPxPageControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I'm using ASPxPageControl and in each page I have a couple of grids. When Im using Sql Server Profiler each time I change Tab there is a query for each grid in each tab sent to the database. Is it possible not to load data for each grid while changing tabs ?

What can I do to make this all work faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If most of the data for these grids stay the same and are for every user the same you can use the **Cache** object to store the retrieved data in.

> What can I do to make this all work faster?

You can also try to optimize the sql statements for performance, put indexes on columns where it makes sense, ...

Helpful links:

- [Cache object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.insert.aspx)
- [Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would use the ASPxPageControl in the callback mode (when the ASPxPageControl.EnableCallbacks property is true).  In this case, the ASPxPageControl will only try to databind only those ASPxGridView which belongs to the active page.  To learn about this mode, please refer to my answer at:

[access object from javascript DevExpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556307/access-object-from-javascript-devexpress)